# Checking for a foreign key before adding it with a sql script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL script which adds a foreign key to a table, as shown below.

```
ALTER TABLE [security].[Pages] WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Pages_PageClasses] FOREIGN KEY ([PageClassId]) REFERENCES [security].[PageClasses]([PageClassId]) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Sometimes the table already has this foreign key so an error is shown when it is run from the Management Studio. Is it possible to add a query to check if the key exists before applying it? Is there a better way to do this? This must work for MS SQL 2005 and 2008.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [OBJECT_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx) function to test for existence.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[security].[FK_Pages_PageClasses]') IS NULL
    ALTER TABLE [security].[Pages] WITH NOCHECK
        ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Pages_PageClasses] FOREIGN KEY ([PageClassId]) REFERENCES [security].[PageClasses]([PageClassId]) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: So simple. Why did everyone else post such complicated replies?

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the existence of the foreign key by looking in the [sys.foreign_keys object catalog view](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189807.aspx):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = object_id(N'[Security].[FK_Pages_PageClasses]') and parent_object_id = object_id(N'[Security].[Pages]'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [security].[Pages] WITH NOCHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Pages_PageClasses] FOREIGN KEY ([PageClassId]) REFERENCES [security].[PageClasses]([PageClassId]) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
END
```